# Expression must be integral or unscoped enum type in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
CString fontroute = me32.szExePath + L"Exo-Regular.ttf";
```

and for some reason Visual Studio 2017 highlights the `L` and says `"Expression must be integral or unscoped enum type"`.

Comment: dear God, why are you using CStrings????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`me32.szExePath` is of type `char*`. You cannot add (`+`) a `wchar_t`-Array (`L"foobar"`) to it.

Construct a temporary `CString` from `me32.szExePath`:

```
CString fontroute = CString{ me32.szExePath } + L"Exo-Regular.ttf";
```

and it should work.